# How to get parameter value from a redirect_uri in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic.

I have a link here:
https://open.weixin.qq.com/connect/qrconnect?appid=wx0f05d08a307a4050&redirect_uri=http://my.duangwifi.cn/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=site/apptest&response_type=code&scope=snsapi_login&state=1234567abc#wechat_redirect

when I use WeChat Scan QR Code function to scan it, the link will redirect to the “redirect_uri” with code as a request parameter:
http://my.duangwifi.cn/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=site/apptest&code=0110c30e667a2ae723b06c542ddc055W&state=1234567abc

I need to get request parameter code's value `0110c30e667a2ae723b06c542ddc055W` in an ionic framework.

Here is the code:

```
<script id="templates/sign-in.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Sign-In">
        <ion-content>
            <div class="list">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src='https://open.weixin.qq.com/connect/qrconnect?appid=wx0f05d08a307a4050&redirect_uri=http://my.duangwifi.cn/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=site/apptest&response_type=code&scope=snsapi_login&state=1234567abc#wechat_redirect' style="width:340px;height:340px;border:0px solid #fff;"  scrolling="no" frameBorder="no"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="padding">
                <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signIn(user)">
                    Sign-In
                </button>
                <!--<p class="text-center">
                  <a href="#/forgot-password">Forgot password</a>
                </p>-->
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</script>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: show us your code so we can better assist you, thanks.

Comment: Hi, @Nikola, thank you for your concerns. I've updated the post.

Comment: are you sure this is all that you have?

Comment: just sign-in part, yes...